# PowerShell - Connect to Entra/Azure with cert auth and use APIs

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-active-directory, certificate

I can connect to a tenant easily with `Connect-AzAccount` and start using the powershell modules to pull information I want. BUT this is not what I am trying to do.
`$vms = Get-AzVM`

I created an app registration in the tenant, and created a certificate for authentication.

I would like my script to use this certificate-based authentication to make the same calls or something similar as above.

Here is the code I been playing with I feel like i'm close.

```
$tenantID       = "aGUID"
$applicationID  = "anotherGUID"
$resourceGroup  = "aGroup"
$subscriptionID = "Azure subscription 1"

# Connect to Entra ID with Certificate
$certThumbPrint = "acertGUID"
$certPass       = ConvertTo-SecureString -String "somepassword" -Force -AsPlainText
#$cert = Get-Item -Path Cert:\CurrentUser\My\$certThumbPrint

# Import the certificate
#$cert = New-Object System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2("C:\temp\cert.pfx", $certPass, "Exportable,PersistKeySet")

# Get the Azure AD application
$azureAdApplication = Get-AzADApplication -ApplicationId $applicationID -TenantId $tenantID

# Get the certificate associated with the application
$cert = Get-AzADAppCredential -ApplicationId $applicationID -TenantId $tenantID | Where-Object { $_.Type -eq "AsymmetricX509Cert" -and $_.Usage -eq "Verify" }

# Authenticate using the certificate
$token = Get-AzAccessToken -ResourceUrl "https://management.azure.com" -TenantId $tenantID -CertificateThumbprint $certThumbPrint -ApplicationId $applicationID -Credential $cert

# Authenticate to Azure AD using the certificate
#$token = Get-AzAccessToken -ResourceUrl "https://management.azure.com" -TenantId $tenantID -ClientId $applicationID -CertificateThumbprint $cert.Thumbprint
$token = Get-AzAccessToken -ResourceUrl "https://management.azure.com" -TenantId $tenantID -ServicePrincipalId $applicationID -CertificateThumbprint $certThumbPrint

# Set the Azure context
Set-AzContext -AadAccessToken $token.Token -SubscriptionId $subscriptionID

# Get a list of VMs
$vms = Get-AzVM

# Display VM information
foreach ($vm in $vms) {
    Write-Host "VM Name: $($vm.Name), Resource Group: $($vm.ResourceGroupName)"
    # Add more details as needed
}
```

Here is my script that creates an app registers it and adds cert authentication

```
Connect-AzAccount

# Create a Certificate and Put it in my Certificate Store
$cert = New-SelfSignedCertificate -CertStoreLocation "cert:\CurrentUser\My" -Subject $applicationName -KeySpec KeyExchange
$keyValue = [System.Convert]::ToBase64String($cert.GetRawCertData())

# Register a new Application in Azure Tenant
$application = New-AzADApplication -DisplayName $applicationName 
$objectId = $application.Id
$applicationId = $application.AppId

Start-Sleep -Seconds 2

# Add this new certificate to the application
New-AzADAppCredential -ApplicationId $applicationId -CertValue $keyValue -EndDate $cert.NotAfter -StartDate $cert.NotBefore 

# Assign API Permissions
## Graph API (Read)
Add-AzADAppPermission -ObjectId $objectId -ApiId "00000003-0000-0000-c000-000000000000" -PermissionId "5f8c59db-677d-491f-a6b8-5f174b11ec1d"

# Export the certificate to a PFX file
$cert | Export-PfxCertificate -FilePath $certFilePath -Password (ConvertTo-SecureString -String $certPassword -Force -AsPlainText)
Write-Host "Certificate Created and placed in: $($certFilePath)"

# Need to convert ByteArray to Base64 to store it in a Normal Azure Table
$certBytes = [System.IO.File]::ReadAllBytes($certFilePath)
$certBase64 = [System.Convert]::ToBase64String($certBytes)

# Get the Domain the the Account
$tenantDetails = Get-AzTenant
Insert-Row -AZStorageTable "AppCertsTest" -PartitionKey $companyName -RowKey $applicationId -TenantID $tenantId -Domain $tenantDetails.DefaultDomain -CertThumbPrint $cert.Thumbprint -CertBytes $certBase64
Write-Host "Tenant Saved in Azure"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> **Note** that: To fetch the VM details, you need subscription level reader access. And then you can directly `Connect-AzAccount` using certificate-based authentication without generating the token and call the APIs.

When I perform `Connect-AzAccount` using cert-based authentication, the subscription name isn't shown:

```
$Thumbprint = 'CertThumbprint'
$TenantId = 'TenantID'
$ApplicationId = 'AppID'
$subscriptionID = 'SubID'

Connect-AzAccount -CertificateThumbprint $Thumbprint -ApplicationId $ApplicationId -Tenant $TenantId -ServicePrincipal
```

[image]

This means the application doesn't have authorization/access to the subscription.

Hence you have to assign **Reader role** to the Service Principal:

[image]

Now use the below PowerShell script to **`Connect-AzAccount` using certificate-based authentication and fetch the VM details**:

```
$Thumbprint = 'CertThumbprint'
$TenantId = 'TenantID'
$ApplicationId = 'AppID'
$subscriptionID = 'SubID'

Connect-AzAccount -CertificateThumbprint $Thumbprint -ApplicationId $ApplicationId -Tenant $TenantId -ServicePrincipal

# Get a list of VMs
$vms = Get-AzVM

# Display VM information
foreach ($vm in $vms) {
    Write-Host "VM Name: $($vm.Name), Resource Group: $($vm.ResourceGroupName)"
    # Add more details as needed
}
```

[image]

***Output:***

```
VM Name: testvm333, Resource Group: RUK
```

**References:**

[Connect-AzAccount (Az.Accounts) | Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.accounts/connect-azaccount?view=azps-11.1.0)

[Set-AzContext (Az.Accounts) | Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.accounts/set-azcontext?view=azps-11.1.0)

Comment: Thank you, you almost gave me EXACTLY what I was looking for. So I am trying to do this all in powershell, my script creates an app registration a cert applies it, etc. How how would I have my cert based authentication so I can view this subscription all using powershell?

Comment: Do you want to add reader role to the application via Powershell?

Comment: To assign Reader role to the Service Principal, make use of this command `New-AzRoleAssignment -RoleDefinitionName "Reader" -ApplicationId "ServicePrincipalAppID"`  Check [this](https://i.imgur.com/U5XeMnp.png)

Comment: Refer this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.resources/new-azroleassignment?view=azps-11.1.0#example-5